# SSHException: OpenSSH private key file checkints do not match

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to setup an ssh-tunneled connection to a mysql instance to a remote linux server from google colab

the server admin is asking us to use an ssh key instead of a user ssh password.
I got the ssh keys working on my machine and they're good to connect to the server remotely (fro my achine the tunnel is good and access to mysql is good)

But what I need now is to set it up so I can use google colab to connect to the mysql server
unfortunately when I try to get the id_rsa key setup with paramiko I get an error:
SSHException: OpenSSH private key file checkints do not match

the id_rsa keys (private and public) were uploaded to my google drive
and this is how I'm trying to do the setup in colab:

```
#Import Modules Needed to connect to server and mysql 
!pip install paramiko
import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient
import ssl  
!pip install sshtunnel
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
!pip install pymysql
import pymysql
import logging

#set up access to drive
from google.colab import drive
#mount google drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

#get glob to work with files in drive
import glob
#get the shh key files from drive (private and file with ssh key file)
sshfolder_files = glob.glob('drive/MyDrive/.ssh/*')
for file_path in sshfolder_files:
  if 'pass.txt' in file_path:
    passfile_path = file_path
  if 'id_rsa' in file_path and 'pub' not in file_path:
    id_rsa_path = file_path
#get the pass for the id_rsa private key
passfile = open(passfile_path, "r")
passcode = passfile.read()
#set up the key so it can be used to to the the server
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(id_rsa_path, passcode) # <-- here I get the error!
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/pkey.py in _read_private_key_openssh(self, lines, password)
    664 
    665         if checkint1 != checkint2:
--> 666             raise SSHException(
    667                 "OpenSSH private key file checkints do not match"
    668             )

SSHException: OpenSSH private key file checkints do not match
```

Comment: If i were to upload the actual private key (id_rsa file) to the colab server instance, and use the path to it, it works.. but somehow if I do the same by accessing the file from drive as coded above I get the error noted. given that, that file is not persistant, I though of using google drive to store the id_rsa file instead... If there,s an alternative to make it so it's persistent I'd be a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

the error appears to refer to a password string that does not match the password needed to decrypt the id_rsa (private key)

if I make sure that the password (second parameter) of this function `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(id_rsa_path, passcode)` matches exactly the password used for the private key, no error is produced.

Since I was reading the password from a text file, I needed to be very careful ensuring that the line read had only the characters that make up the password, (no extra non-visible characters), so If I using strip() on that line string will take care of new line carachters and empty spaces and using a function like `re.sub('\W_','')` to substitute any non-alphanumerica caracters on the string should ensure the password read from the file matches the one I used for the private key when it was generated (assuing that only alphanumeric characters were used.